# Help with adjusted r-square

Tags: r, r-squared

What does it mean if my adjusted r-squared decreases between my bivariate and multivariate regression models? is this a bad or good thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $R^2_{adj.}$ is a version of the $R^2$ which is adjusted for multiple regressors. Whereas the $R^2$ rises the more regressors you add, even when there are irrelevant, the $R^2_{adj.}$ stays robust.

$$R^2=1-\frac{SSR}{SST};\quad R^2_{adj.}=1-\frac{SSR/(n-p-1)}{SST/(n-1)}$$

Hence, when you add more regressors to your bivariate model, and then your $R^2_{adj.}$ decreases, the model tends to deteriorate and you might call it a "bad thing."

Comment: does this mean the bivariate model is better? Z is the third regressor or a confounding variable.

Comment: @LouisRich Yes, I would consider that model with the higher $R^2_{adj.}$ better, because it explains more variance in the dependent variable. Or put the other way round, the added regressors contribute nothing but "blur" to the model.

Comment: that's perfect, thank you so much. So would this mean that Z is not a confounding variable? and would provide support for hypothesis in the bivariate model?

Comment: @LouisRich I would'nt conclude that solely from the $R^2_{adj.}$. The effect of the $X$ variable is probably more important (does it change considerable? does it change sign? does it get insignificant?).

Comment: HI X in the bivraite model 1.2052, STD error 0.1603, p value= 2.58e-12 ***.

Comment: X in the multivariate model Estimate 0.4310, Std error 0.1876, p value= 0.02320 *

Comment: @LouisRich That was actually meant to ask yourself. But I would tentatively conclude, the relation between $Y$ and $X$ is confounded by $Z$ because $X$ changes quite a lot. However, after adjusting for $Z$, $X$ is still significant at the 95% level.

Comment: thank you for your help

Comment: You're welcome @LouisRich! Please consider to [mark the answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: would you be able to help with another question?

Comment: @LouisRich Put your other issue into a new question as is customary on Cross Validated. I will then take a look and the others too! ;)

Comment: thanks, sorry im very new to all of this

Comment: @LouisRich Really no problem, I'm happy to have guided you somehow through one of your first questions.